# How to draw the conic hull (i.e., geometry interpretation)?

Tags: convex-analysis

Recently, I am learning the optimization project and I have encountered the concept of conic hull.

> [image]

As the picture shows, the literal interpretation is clear, but I want to know what's the meaning of the two pictures that in the bottom. Do they describe the formation process of conic hull?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $\bar x\in$ConvexHull then the graphic represents all $\bar x - O$

Comment: The represent the conic hulls of a set of points and of a curve.